# Searching for a pattern in a column bash

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I'm running a program on bash that works with csv files. 
I need to search a column for a pattern.

> Input

```
column1,column2,column3,column4
1,5000,1000,3000,1000
2,3600,3000,6582,5840
3,2000,1500,100,1000
4,1000,500,30,1000
```

--

> Condition

Condition: Obtain the values in column 1 that are greater than 2000.

> Desired output

```
Column1
1,5000
2,3600
```

I have tried the following code without success:

```
awk '{ if($2 > 2000) { print } }' p.csv > pattern.csv
```

Comment: people spend their time and efforts to help you to understand some points or to replay to your question, therefore you have to be faithful for their effort and accept their answer

Comment: column 1 in your example is the digits 1 through 4 and you have no header for the 5th column, just data. [edit] your question to fix the text, code, and/or example so they're all consistent with each other and accurately state what you're asking for help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==1{print $1}; NR>1 && $2>2000{print $1,$2}' FS=',' OFS=',' file
```

Output:

```
column1
1,5000
2,3600
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)
`NR` is current row number.

Comment: You missed the uppercase 'C' in `Column1` ;-)